# How can I navigate in WPF MVVM page

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, navigation

I have viewlist in which contain elements. When I click on them, my `ItemViewModel` handler clicks. Then I can select information about that element. Afthe I must to open new page in which will be all information about it. For example like hypertext in browser.

```
 <Border MaxHeight="300" MaxWidth="1140" CornerRadius="25" Margin="73,269,65,182">
            
 
            <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="0,0,10,-3">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <ListView Width="1031" ItemsSource="{Binding GetTopItem}" 
                           ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                           Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#DD000000"
                          x:Name="ListBook">
                    <ListView.DataContext>
                        <vm:BookMainVM/>
                    </ListView.DataContext>

                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border HorizontalAlignment="Left" CornerRadius="25,25,25,25"  BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FF474747" Height="288" Margin="0,0,0,0" MouseDown="Border_MouseDown" >
                                <Grid  Grid.Column="0" Height="Auto" Width="216" Margin="-1" IsEnabled="False">

                                    <Grid.InputBindings>
                                        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick"
                                         Command="{Binding DataContext.DelegateCommands,
                                         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
                                         CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                        </MouseBinding>
                                    </Grid.InputBindings>

                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="49*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="18*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Border CornerRadius="25,25,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Img_src}" Stretch="Fill" />
                                        </Border.Background>
                                    </Border>
                                    <Label Content="{Binding Rate}"  Background="#FFBFBFBF" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Meiryo UI" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <Border CornerRadius="0,0,25,25"  Grid.Row="2" Background="#FF8F8F8F">
                                        <TextBlock  Margin="6,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="2" Height="61" Width="190"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
```

```
  class ItemMainVM:ViewModel
     {
        private LibraryModel libraryModel;
        private ItemDb itemsDb;
    
        private const string Dir = "D:\\repos\\Frame\\Frame\\src";

        public ItemMainVM()
        {
            libraryModel = new LibraryModel();
            itemsDb = new BooksDb();
            DelegateCommands = new DelegateCommand(o => EventHandler(o));
        }


        public ObservableCollection<BookPreviewInfo> GetTopItem
        {
            get
            { 
                return libraryModel.GetTopItems();
            }
        }

   
        public ICommand DelegateCommands { get; }
        

        public void EventHandler(dynamic item)
        {
            itemDb.SelectItemId(item.Id);

        }
    }
```

Code Behind is empty.
When I click an element and executing `EventHandler` in `ItemMainVM`. And next must be create new page with new `ElementViewModel`.
`ElementViewModel` should to get information about element in `ItemMainVM`.

Comment: Please don't use `dynamic` when you don't need to. The chance on runtime exceptions is big.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen
i don't know how to convert object in item. If (Item)item i have error

Comment: Just cast it: `DelegateCommands=new DelegateCommand(o => EventHandler((MyItem)o));`

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen  State Error CS0716 Cannot convert to static type 'VisualStyleElement.ListView.Item' Frame